# Why won't my React Component render multiple times?

Tags: reactjs

I am brushing up on some React but I am having an issue with multiple renders.

I have a List component, it accepts an array of "content" and builds a list from it.

I want it to render the same list of the same content 3-4 times, as you can see below.

However, it actually only renders ONE of these lists...

Why won't it do what I want it to though?

I tried using a loop and adding a different key prop on each (the value of i), etc but to no luck and most articles I have read are quite convoluted and useless.

Here is my current code:

```js
//main.jsx
const React = require("react");
const ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
const List = require("./components/List.jsx");
const textNodes = [{
  id: 1,
  text: "ok"
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: "yep"
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: "aye"
}, {
  id: 4,
  text: "hey bro"
}];

ReactDOM.render( < List content = {
    textNodes
  }
  />, document.getElementById("stage"));
ReactDOM.render(
 <List content={textNodes}/ > , document.getElementById("stage"));
ReactDOM.render( < List content = {
    textNodes
  }
  />, document.getElementById("stage"));
ReactDOM.render(
 <List content={textNodes}/ > , document.getElementById("stage"));

//List.jsx
const React = require("react");
const ListItem = require("./ListItem.jsx");

const List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    let listItems = this.props.content.map((item) => < ListItem key = {
        item.id
      }
      itemText = {
        item.text
      }
      />);
  return (
   <ul>
    {listItems}
   </ul >
    )
  }
});

module.exports = List;

//ListItem.jsx
const React = require("react");
const ListItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return ( < li >
      < h4 > {
        this.props.itemText
      } < /h4>
   </li >
    )
  }
});

module.exports = ListItem;
```

Comment: It looks like you're rendering everything to the same div. This will overwrite the contents of the div.

Comment: Also formatting your code would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're rendering the same content into the same `div` multiple times - each time you render it, you overwrite the previous one.

Instead of doing this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<List content={textNodes} />, document.getElementById("stage"));
```

four times, do this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <List content={textNodes} />
        <List content={textNodes} />
        <List content={textNodes} />
        <List content={textNodes} />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('stage')
);
```

Comment: Works perfect now, rookie mistake much :(!

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct in 6 minutes, it wont allow me to do it until then. Thanks!

Comment: Happens to us all :-S

Comment: Yeah, its all part of the developer cycle isnt it :P

Answer (score 0):

You render all Lists into the same html element (with id stage), which overwrite each other.

What you need to do instead is write another component - your entry point of the application and there render your multiple lists. Then you will have your entry point rendered into html element with id stage which contains your multiple lists:

```
const textNodes = [{
  id: 1,
  text: "ok"
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: "yep"
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: "aye"
}, {
  id: 4,
  text: "hey bro"
}];

const List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    let listItems = this.props.content.map((item) => < ListItem key = {
        item.id
      }
      itemText = {
        item.text
      }
      />);
        return (
            <ul>
                {listItems}
            </ul >
    )
  }
});

const ListItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return ( < li >
      < h4 > {
        this.props.itemText
      } < /h4>
            </li >
    )
  }
});

const EntryPoint = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return ( <div>
            < List content = {textNodes} />
      < List content = {textNodes} />
      < List content = {textNodes} />
   </div>)
  }
})

ReactDOM.render( <EntryPoint />, document.getElementById("stage"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <List content={textNodes}/ > , document.getElementById("stage"));
```

This line renders your Lists on the same div, with id "stage", on your template. So the one List you see is the third rendered List. You should different div with different id to render all three Lists onto.